# How to get the from position in OnPageChangeListener of a viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

in a viewpager's `OnPageChangeListener`'s `onPageSelected` you have the current selected position (i.e the current displayed one) How do you get the previous position from which it was scrolled to this current position?

Comment: i think you have to maintain that every time on page selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the fromPosition (i.e the position from where the viewpager is being scrolled from in `onPageScrolled` callback, the position value in this callback method is nothing but the position from which the scroll is being initiated, therefore when onPageSelected is called the position stored from onPageScrolled will be the previous position from which the scroll was started.

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    private int fromPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        fromPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.v("onPageSelected", "scrolled from position " + fromPosition)
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

Comment: this works when scrolling right to left in the viewpager, if scrolling in the opposite direction it does not e.g. right to left `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` then left to right `4, 3, 2, 1, 0`  When it should be `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`

Comment: @DJ-DOO why should it be 5,4,3,2,1 ? viewpager maintains a 0 based list.

Comment: because at that point you are at page 5, having scrolled from 4 to 5 so when you scrolling the opposite direction you are scrolling from page 5.

Comment: @DJ-DOO when you go from left to right it should be 4,3,2,1,0 because the value that is getting printed in onPageSelected is the from position value, when you go from psoition 4 back to 3, then value getting printed is 4 which is as intended, idk what the confusion is here? its a 0 based list